# How can I get the collection page name in Liquid (Shopify)?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I get the collection page name in shopify ?

Maybe I am at the collection "Cars"

then I want to check if the collection == "Cars"

how can I read the query parameter in Liquid ?

With this snipped I can check in which page I am but I dont get the name of the collection

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Collection Handle](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/collection#collection-handle) to check for that.

```
{% if collection.handle == 'cars' %}
```